# How to customise Vega (not-lite) utc type with non-default dynamic formats

Tags: vega

I'm using something similar to the following for the x axis, but at a particular zoom level it shows the axis format of "Nov 07". In the UK it is confused with year. Is there anywhere to change it to "07 Nov"? However, I want to retain the other more granular formats e.g. down to time.

"scales": [
{
"name": "x",
"type": "utc",
"domain": {"data": "moviesNew", "field": "Rotten Tomatoes Rating"},
"range": "width"
},
...

Answer (score 0):

Vega axes has property format that accepts d3 format specification. The axes text label string can also be formatted.

Example format for "07 Nov":

```
[axes]
...
"format": "%e %b",
...
```

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/axes/

https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/time/#timeFormat

https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Comment: Thanks, but not quite the issue I've got. The utc data type has a little more behind the scenes that changes the format based on the domain of the time values e.g. if the values were all from today, the scale would be in hours. What I'm looking for is where is the format for a given level of granularity kept, potentially to change it out for your kindly suggested formatting option.